# R - Pull max of columns in one data frame to varying # of columns in another data frame

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I currently have 2 data frames and need to fill about 25 columns with values from another data frame that has varying values for each column in the original data frame. Here is some reproducible code (not my actual case but will give a sense for what my data is like).

```
set.seed(1)

val <- dnorm(rnorm(1200))
bin <- ifelse(val > .39,1,0)
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(data=bin,ncol=120,nrow=10))
colnames(df1) <- c(paste0("rule",c(1:100)),paste0("cond",c(1:20)))
df1[,101:120] <- 0

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3,nrow=100))
colnames(df2) <- c("rule","category","value")
df2$rule <- c(paste0("rule",c(1:100)))
df2$category <- c(paste0("cond",c(rep(1:20,5))))
df2$value <- sample(c(rep(0,10),rep(2,5),4,6,8),100, replace = TRUE)
```

Now, I've created a for loop that grabs the necessary data that I'd like in df1 from df2 but my actual data set has over 4 million rows and the for loop takes forever. Here's the code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1))
{
        myRules   <- colnames(df1[i, 1:100])[df1[i, 1:100] == 1]
        myCatVals <- df2[df2$rule %in% myRules, 2:3]
        myMaxes   <- aggregate(myCatVals,list(myCatVals$cat),max)
        df1[, (colnames(df1) %in% myMaxes$cat)] <- myMaxes$value
}
```

This loop is designed to match the rules that have a value of 1 in df1 to the categories and values in df2. But since there are more rules than categories there can be redundancies (i.e. the columns from df1 could be 30 and only be matched to 20 unique categories). Therefore, I only want to pull the maximum value among each category and fill those values in the 'cond_" columns of df1.

Is there a way to use apply, mapply, or some other function to accomplish what this loop does in a faster way?

Comment: You can use `data.table`.

Comment: I doubt that `apply` or `mapply` will improve anything. I think that it will be helpful though if you would explain what are you actually trying to do in that `for` loop instead of just posting the code. Nice first question btw.

Comment: Editted the question to explain the purpose of the `for` loop.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel could you please expound on that? After looking at the `data.table` package, it isn't clear to me how it will help me with this.

Comment: basically you're using a loop but it would be better to vectorized your operations or use binary search in case of join operations (what `data.table` do).

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I guess I'm not as versed in the binary search and join methods as I should be. The process is still eluding me. Vectorizing operations over a varying number of vectors for each row is making my head spin.